# Sending SMS in yii2

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I'm using **two** models in one controller. one of them is database model **(model)** another model is for sending sms **(smsModel)**.

I have problem in smsModel.

I got this error in my result:

```
Class 'fcadmin\models\SoapClient' not found
```

How can I fix it?

My controller:

```
public function actionCreate($id) {

        $model = new Requestresult();
        $smsModel = new SmsSender();
        $request_model = Request::findOne(['id' => $id]);

        $model->CodeKargah = $request_model->CodeKargah;
        $model->month = $request_model->month;
        $model->trackingCode = $request_model->trackingCode;
        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {
            $smsModel->sendSms('09193452126', 'sdf');
            return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
        } else {
            return $this->render('create', [
                        'model' => $model,
            ]);
        }
    }
```

smsModel:

```
public function sendSms($to, $text) {
    $options = [
        'login' => 'myusername',
        'password' => 'mypassword'
    ];
    $client = new SoapClient('http://sms.hostiran.net/webservice/?WSDL', $options);
    $messageId = $client->send($to, $text);
    sleep(3);
    return ($client->deliveryStatus($messageId));
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to read up about namespaces. If you're in a namespace and don't tell PHP that you want to use the global namespace, it will look for classes of name x in the current namespace.

In your case you need to be using `new \SoapClient`.